# accessing parent contents from inside iframe(on the same server machine) jquery working in firefox and IE but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am developing a music site , site contains a parent page with an iframe and a player. when menu is click the src of iframe is change depending on menu item clicked.In one page iframe contains music items. When a music is clicked inside iframe, i want to add that music in the playlist(contains in the parent).
My jQuery code is working in Firefox and Internet Explorer but in chrome. it gives an error below..

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from
>   accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports
>   must match. ...

here is my code

```
$('span[name=add]').click(function(){

    var song = $(this).attr("song");
    var cover = $(this).attr("cover");
    var artist = $(this).attr("artist");
    window.parent.$('#playlist').prepend('<li song="'+song+'" cover="'+cover+'"artist="'+artist+'">'+song+'</li>');
    window.parent.$('#playlist').trigger('change');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is to stop phishing.

I haven't done this to manipulate DOM before, but when I bumped into this error, I found that this pattern worked.

1. Create function in parent window.
2. Call function from iframe.

Haven't tested this exact code, just for example.

Parent

```
window.newHtml = "";
window.setHtml = function() {
    $('#someElement').html(window.newHtml);
};
```

Iframe

```
newHtml = "<p>yo!</p>";
setHtml();
```